# VB.net Average of 3 numbers two different ways. Beginners question

Tags: vb.net, average

I have a form that has 3 text boxes for 3 input values, along with a list box for output. I need the user to be able to input 3 different numbers and click a button to find the average. I'm not really sure how to do/approach this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Still Stuck....

```
Private Sub btnAverage_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     
Handles btnAverage.Click
    Dim a As Integer = CInt(txtone.Text)
    Dim b As Integer = CInt(txtTwo.Text)
    Dim c As Integer = CInt(txtThree.Text)
    Dim average As Integer
    average = (a + b + c) / 3
    lstOutput.Text = average
```

Comment: What part(s) of it aren't you sure about?

Comment: 1.  Get the data from each field into integers (or reals as appropriate).
2.  Add them up.
3.  Divide the sum by 3.0.
4.  Display the result.
What parts of this are a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you unsure about how to convert the input to numbers?  If so use the CInt function.

```
Public Sub OnAverageClick(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles AverageButton.Click

    Dim input1 as Integer = CInt(textBox1.Text)
    Dim input2 as Integer = CInt(textBox2.Text)
    Dim input3 as Integer = CInt(textBox3.Text)
    Dim average = (input1 + input2 + input3) / 3

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok now I feel dumb. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would use Integer.TryParse instead.

Comment: @Dustin, you are one step closer to true addiction to SO!

Answer (score 0):

@JaredPar

I would use Integer.TryParse instead.

Comment: Yes TryParse would be a safer method of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This function calculates the Average of any number of non-zero values:

```
''' <summary>Calcula el Promedio de los Valores ingresados.
''' Sólo tiene en cuenta los Valores mayores que 0.</summary>
''' <param name="diasValores">Valores a Calcular</param>
Function PromedioValores(ByVal ParamArray diasValores() As Integer)
    'Esta funcion calcula el promedio de los valores ingresados como parametro
    Dim result As Double = 0
    If diasValores.Length <= 0 Then Exit Function
    Dim cant As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(diasValores, 1)
        If diasValores(i) > 0 Then
            cant = cant + 1
            result += diasValores(i)
        End If
    Next i
    If result > 0 Then
        result = result / cant
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

Use:

```
Me.TextBox1.Text = PromedioValores(10, 0, 0, 15, 0, 12, 12, 0)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
protected sub on_btn_click()

listbox1.items.add(new listitem((integer.parse(textbox1.text) + integer.parse(textbox2.text) + integer.parse(textbox3.text)) / 3 ))

end sub
```

Comment: while your answer looks correct, I think you should explain it since the OP is admittedly a newbie.

Comment: You're adding items to a list not adding the values.